# Why Angular4 Router render elements outside <router-outlet>

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-router

I have used Angular4 router in my application.
I've planned to render child components using a `<router-outlet>` container.
But what I've observed is child components are rendered next to `<router-outlet>`.

Expected:

```
<router-outlet>
   <child-component/>
</router-outlet>
```

Actual:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<child-component/>
```

***Any possible reason why Angular decided to make this work like this?***
    ***Router configuration used is exactly same as given in https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5***

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8529#issuecomment-217718704

Comment: you could still style your components using adjacent selector in css:
router-outlet + *{
  // your style
}

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood `router-outlet` uses [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) to manipulate the DOM. Essentially `router-outlet` element is itself a view container:

```
    @Directive({selector: 'router-outlet', exportAs: 'outlet'})
    export class RouterOutlet implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
      constructor(..., private location: ViewContainerRef, ...

      attach(ref: ComponentRef<any>, activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
        ...
        this.location.insert(ref.hostView);
      }
```

Using `ViewContainerRef` is the way DOM [should be manipulated in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02). 
The `ViewContainerRef` is more of a placeholder for where the components will be injected into the DOM / rendered rather than a container for the component.
So any element inserted with the help of view container **is inserted alongside the view container element, not inside**.

[Here is the one](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8529#issuecomment-217718704) possible reason for enabling this behavior mentioned by @yurzui.